# send devise registration mails using reque background job

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, resque

I am using rails 3 with devise for authentication and resque for handling background job
Is there a way to send devise registration mails using resque ?

https://github.com/defunkt/resque
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following gem, this will send all the mails from devise through resque queue https://github.com/zapnap/resque_mailer

Comment: Just remember you can toy around with the `config.mailer = "Devise::Mailer"` setting in devise.rb